# How to get RecyclerView item count?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Hey i have **recyclerview list** like episode 1, episode 2, episode3, ... how to count total item and set as textview like current `episode = episode(total items)`

here my adapter

```
public class EpisodeAdapter  extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<EpisodeAdapter.EpisodeHolder>{
    private List<Episode> episodeList;
    public EpisodeAdapter(List<Episode> episodeList) {
        this.episodeList = episodeList;
    }
    @Override
    public EpisodeHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_episode , null);
        EpisodeAdapter.EpisodeHolder mh = new EpisodeAdapter.EpisodeHolder(v);
        return mh;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(EpisodeHolder holder, final int position) {
        if (episodeList.get(position).getImage()!=null){
            Picasso.with(SerieActivity.this).load(episodeList.get(position).getImage()).into(holder.image_view_item_episode_thumbail);
        }else{
            Picasso.with(SerieActivity.this).load(poster.getImage()).into(holder.image_view_item_episode_thumbail);
        }
        holder.text_view_item_episode_title.setText(episodeList.get(position).getTitle());
        if (episodeList.get(position).getDuration() !=  null){
            holder.text_view_item_episode_duration.setText(episodeList.get(position).getDuration());
        }
    }
```

Comment: episodeList.size() it's your total item in recyclerview.

Answer (score 7):

Get total item count from adapter of set in recyclerView.

recyclerView & adapter can't be null, otherwise you can find total
items.

```
recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
int i = recyclerViewAdapter.getItemCount();
```

i is your count of items present in your recyclerview

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
int count = 0;
if (recyclerViewInstance.getAdapter() != null) {
     count = recyclerViewInstance.getAdapter().getItemCount();
}
```

Or, if you have a reference to your adapter, simply call:

```
 int count = 0;
  if (mAdapter != null) {
     count = mAdapter.getItemCount();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

RecyclerView.Adapter already has function [getItemCount](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html?hl=en#getItemCount()) for getting total item count.

But this will only work if you override the function and return the size of your list

```
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (episodeList != null)
            return episodeList.size();
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will work for you.
You can retrieve count by using the ArrayList's `size()` method. So, in your case you can calculate using `episodeList.size()`.

For setting the list size to TextView in Activity.

```
yourTextView.setText(""+ episodeList.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override getItemCount() method and then use it.

```
@Override
int getItemCount() {
  episodeList.size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin extension:

```kotlin
/** Return null if don't adapter. */
val RecyclerView.itemCount: Int? get() = adapter?.itemCount
```

Or for single use:

```kotlin
val itemCount = binding.recyclerView?.adapter?.itemCount
```